# Steps to implement search(edittext) in my android application

Tags: android

i am new to developing android apps.In my app i have a listview which displays the items which are stored in SQLite,now i need to implement a search which will search and retrieve the item from SQLite database and display in listview.

Comment: retrieve all data in array list.then search what you want to search in array list.don't fire query every time for sqlite for searching

Comment: Here you go https://developer.android.com/training/search/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the hints ... since i'm a beginner it would be great if you can provide me with an example or tutorial to do it.

Comment: Thanks @Egor, but i would like to implement search functionality using edittext and not a searchview :)

Comment: SearchView is just a UI element which provides a convenient set of controls to make it easier for you to implement search. If you want to  use EditText you just need to implement the UI and the callbacks manually, but the search mechanism integration remains the same.

Comment: @user3400674 use SimpleCursorAdapter and setFilterQueryProvider

Answer (score 0):

Well u have to get text from edit text like

```
Edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                            int before, int count) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                get text over here 

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                            int count, int after) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }


    });
```

then search that text in your database and then again set adapter of your listview your problem is solved
you have to clear the array list or list if you are using then again add values and then update listview :)